# Update an invenory in anylogic

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

If I have a production system that produces lets say cars, and the machines (resource pool) have failure rate and repair rate. For repairing, the spare parts inventory should be checked for availabiltiy, then repairing.  It is possible to update the spare parts level! Where it is not an entity to this model? If not, any idea :)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Try to ask very specific questions here only, several if need be. Also, please show what research you have already done and screenshots help a lot. cheers

Comment: You're saying you need parts to repair a machine? To model such a behaviour, in your resource pool select the flowchart option to model the repair task. That flowchart should verify if you have enough parts (it can be a simple variable) and if so, starts some operation (a delay for example). When the repair is over, update the stock.